# Behavior of a loop within a single TRANSACTION

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following structure:

```
PROCEDURE A

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    WHILE <loops 20 times>
        BEGIN

         --10 minute script     
         --INSERT a single record into table X

        END
COMMIT TRANSACTION


PROCEDURE B - This is run via the agent every 10 minutes it scans table X for any new entries and if it finds any it sends an e-mail
```

If everything runs ok 20 new records will be added to table X - will these records only get added to X if all 20 loops have been successful? If the loop gets to it's 5th iteration and then errors will the first 4 records be committed ?

Comment: What is it, exactly, you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse table X is actually a control table for emails that need to be sent out via `db_sendmail` ... `PROCEDURE B` is scanning looking for new mails that need to be sent out. I only want either _all_ the mails for `PROC A` to go or _none_ of them to go. What I want to avoid is someof the mails going.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, holding a transaction open for 10 minutes is evil. Holding a transaction open 20 times for 10 minutes is ... well, 20 times more evil. Long lived transactions are very very very damaging and they cause serious problems in locking and blocking, log use and growth, recovery problems. Never design anything that has transactions longer than *seconds*. Time for you to revisit the fundamental issue you're trying to solve and come up with a radically different solution.

As for the core question: transactions can use savepoints in such iterations, so that iteration 1-4 are saved (committed) even if iteration 5 hits an issue and has to rollback. The trick is to rollback up to a savepoint, not completely. Follow the same pattern as in [Exception Handling and Nested Transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/). Note that not *every* error is recoverable, some errors will force a complete rollback (eg. deadlock is a typical example).

Comment: ....I'm not as evil as you think; I've taken the actual times and exaggerated them into a more extreme situation to hopefully get a better answer and then safer, more defensive code.

Comment: ok maybe a radical change like: I could simply add each row, at the end of each loop iteration to an intermediate temp table. Then once the code has finished looping it could `insert` all of the data in the temp table - what do you think? Just going back to _"seconds"_ - are you implying that a transaction of anything less than a minute is ok ?

Comment: For what you described (send all mails or none) a staging table seems appropriate. This way you can prepare all the work in individual transactions and then, in one single transaction, transform all items accumulated in the staging table into sp_send_mail calls.

Comment: As for the transaction duration comment: the shorter, the better. One minute I would consider it way too long.

Comment: ok - so when you say _seconds_ you really mean _"instantaneous => 1 second"_ ?

Comment: Agreed, staging table is the way to go here.  I've dealt with a couple of similar processes here.  Keep in mind that sending the mail doesn't actually mean it's going to be delivered.  Also, _sending_ the emails can fail unrecoverably at any time, given the way email works - you may want to keep logs of what you were able to 'deliver' to the servers.  Depending on how your mail server is set up, you may be able to 'batch' the emails in some fashion (dunno, never worked on one...).

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is not 100 percent straight forward:

They will be added to the data pages in memory as they are inserted at the end of each loop, and if another process ran using READ UnCOMITTED or NO LOCK then they would be able to see these inserts. This is called Dirty Reads and the default isolation level of REAd COMMITED protects against this, but it also means transactions will be blocked from reading it under this level, until you loop completes.

However, SQL Server can choose to flush the dirty pages to disc at any time. By this, I mean before the end of the transaction, at the end of the transaction or after the transaction completes.

What is certain, is that the writes will be flushed to the transaction log at the end of the transaction, before the commit. This is how SQL Server gauruntees data will not be lost in the event of the database going down. This is called WAL or Write Ahead Logging.

Comment: can I amend the code in `PROC B` so that it is forced to **not** read `UNCOMMITTED` data ?

Comment: Unless you have specifically set read uncommitted or used a no lock hint, the default is read committed, which will protect against this? It will just sit there and wait for proc a to finish unless there is a lock timeout set, when it will fall over